# How to fix ngFor list issue in --prod mode?

Tags: angular, ngfor

I'm looping over array in my angular web application, the array is updated to and from firebase and fetched from firebase directly. it shows correctly in development mode, but the list/index keep flipping and swapping around with every key stroke in `--prod` mode only.

Check this detailed video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VQV9_iGRfi0) showing the issue more clearly and comparing serve with `--prod` and without `--prod`

Service Code :

```
 getDonors(projectUrl: string) {
    return this.db.collection(`Donors`, ref => ref.where('projectUrl', '==', projectUrl)).snapshotChanges().pipe(map(
      snaps => {
        const donors = snaps.map(
          snap => {
            return {
              donorId: snap.payload.doc.id,
              data: snap.payload.doc.data()
            };
          }
        );
        return donors;
      }
    ));
  }
```

Component Code :

```
  ngOnInit() {

    this.companyUrl = 'someName';
    this.eventUrl = this.route.snapshot.params['eventUrl'];
    this.projectUrl = this.route.snapshot.params['projectUrl'];
    console.log(this.companyUrl + '-' + this.eventUrl + '-' + this.projectUrl);

    this.services.getDonors(this.projectUrl).subscribe(
      d => {
        this.donorsList = d;
      }
    );

  }
```

HTML Code

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let donor of donorsList.reverse()">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <p class="m-0">{{ donor.data.title }} / {{ donor.data.name }}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <p class="m-0">{{ donor.data.eventUrl }}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <p class="m-0">{{ donor.data.amount }} ريال</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1 text-center">
      <button class="btn btn-success btn-sm" (click)="onEdit(donor.donorId)">تعديل</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1 text-center">
        <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" (click)="onDelete(donor.donorId)">X</button>
      </div>
    <hr>
  </div>
</ng-container>
```

This issue doesn't appear in `development` mode

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix ngFor list issue in --prod mode only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56039876/how-to-fix-ngfor-list-issue-in-prod-mode-only)

Comment: I'd say delete the other one, this is more descriptive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar problem on my application.

The problem comes from `.reverse()` in your html.

Everytime it's called, (which means on each event), reverse took place an you array is modified.

This means anything from a click event to data received from an ajax call causes the change detection to be triggered and then `donorsList.reverse()` to be called.

**You can try** to replace `donorsList.reverse()` by `donorsList.slice().reverse()`. So you will not mutate the original array.

Comment: It worked, i was busy trying to fix it with other methods. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can write this as:

```
getDonors(projectUrl: string) {
    return this.db.collection(`Donors`, ref => ref.where('projectUrl', '==', projectUrl)).snapshotChanges()
    .pipe(
      map(snaps => snaps.map(snap => ({
          donorId: snap.payload.doc.id,
          data: snap.payload.doc.data()
        })
      )
    );
}
```

Also do not place logic like `reverse()` in the view. Do this in ngOnInit:

```
    this.services.getDonors(this.projectUrl)
                 .subscribe(d => this.donorsList = d.reverse());.
```

Your issue arises most likely from fetching unordered data from the data source, unless snapshotChanges() is ordered by default, Every time you update the data it will return the data in a different order. Try using some sort of ordering in your query.

Also, to ensure efficent and consistent updates in an `*ngFor` directive use a `trackBy` function.

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let donor of donorsList; trackBy: trackByFn">
```

In your class:

```
  trackByFn(index, element) {
    return element.donorId;
  }
```

There is nothing wrong with the `--prod` flag to cause this issue. There's thousands of angular apps in production using `*ngFor`. It's something to do with your ordering logic and a lack of `trackBy`

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed response, I'm very happy with the changes you provided. Thanks Again.